# Word order of asking questions using auxiliary verbs

Tags: word-order, questions, auxiliary-verbs

To me the sentence: "*To whom, might I ask, am I speaking?*" is a changed word order of "*Might I ask to whom am I speaking?*", and it's not grammatical.

I think it should be: "*Might I ask to whom I'm speaking?*"
Agree?

Comment: Why do you think it's not grammatical?

Comment: **Edit**: Because of the may/might/ part when it's at the beginning of a question. Like *Might I ask what your name is?* and not "*Might I ask what is your name?*".

Comment: There's no rule that says *may* or *might* or any other modal has to come at the beginning of a sentence; it can be used in an interjection like that.  Sentences like "The Queen, I might add, is a lover of horses" are quite common and grammatical.

Comment: Please also read [this](http://learnersdictionary.com/qa/Questions-with-might-may-can-permission-suggestions).

Comment: The examples on that page are different from yours.  In a sentence like *"Can I take your bags?"*, yes, the auxiliary has to come first, because the structure is *(auxiliary verb) (subject) (main verb phrase)?*: (Can) (I) (take (your bags)). You can't reorder it, because it doesn't make sense to say *"Your, can I take, bags?"*, because you're breaking up phrases that have to stay together.  But...

Comment: Your example is different, because it's really a form of *Might I ask "To whom am I speaking?"*  "To whom am I speaking?" is already its own completely-formed sentence.  That's why you can move *might I ask* around in a way that you could not if it were the "main auxiliary" (if that makes sense) of the sentence.  It's just serving a kind of rhetorical function there that's unlike its critical function in *"Might I take your bags?"*

Comment: I agree with you. But I think the sentence can be rephrase like this "Might I ask who I'm speaking to?"

Comment: @stangdon: I meant the sentences like, *Might I ask how you heard about our company?* on that site.

Comment: Why is it "To whom"? Shouldn't it be "To who"?

Comment: @SovereignSun: Both are acceptable and used but in the formal English, in this case that _whom_ is an object, that form is correct.

Comment: @SovereignSun - The statement is "I am speaking to **him**", so the correct question form is to "To **whom** am I speaking?"  But a lot of native speaker have stopped using *whom* and just use *who* all the time.

Comment: @Abbasi - In *"Might I ask how you heard about our company?"*, yes, the modal has to come first.  As before, "how you heard about our company" is a phrase that doesn't stand on its own.

Comment: @SovereignSun *Whom* is markedly formal, so it fits well with pied-piping (moving the preposition to the front with the *wh*-word), which is also markedly formal: *To whom am I speaking?*  On the other hand, *who* is normal, and so is a lack of pied-piping: *Who am I speaking to?* is more common in normal speech.   Mixing the two is a bit strange, so *To who am I speaking?* sounds odd.

Comment: @snailplane yes, I read about it already. Thanks. Still I agree with **standon**. *Whom=him*, *Who=he*. So it actually should be **whom**

Comment: @SoverignSun That is simply wrong.  I'm sorry you were fed the same myth so many people spread about *whom = him, who = he*.  There is a correspondence there but the usage in most cases differs; they simply aren't the same thing grammatically.

Comment: @SovereignSun [Arnold Zwicky wrote up a description here](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004084.html).  As he demonstrates: "This is just a fact of life.  Though they are to some degree parallel, WHO and the ordinary personal pronouns differ in the way Form1 and Form2 are distributed."  See his note at the bottom for why he calls them "Form1" and "Form2" instead of "nominative" and "accusative" in this description.

Answer (score 1):

As Stangdon has aptly put it, "Might I ask" is an interjection which can more succinctly be called a parenthetic clause set off from the main sentence by intonation in speech and by comas or the likes in writing—explanatory or qualifying clause not essential to the main construction. There are two inversions— one of 'might' which is just rhetorical only to add flavour and the other is the inversion of 'am' for questioning. The former is optional but the latter is a necessity.

If 'whom' is used, it is better that 'to' be prefixed to it. But if 'who' is preferred leave 'to' at the tail end. So first two sentences are quite right.

The suggested line can only be accepted if we just view inversion of "Might" for questioning (not rhetorical) bereft of  quotation.

We fail to agree in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Your version and the original version are both correct. English allows some flexibility in word order.

The original is more colloquial and you're unlikely to find it in a formal text. Your edit is more formal.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on the other answers, I would say that both sound equally "correct". However, the first sentence,

> To whom, might I ask, am I speaking?

Puts the emphasis on "to whom", and almost sounds confrontational.

> Might I ask to whom I'm speaking?

Sounds more like a polite request.

I should say though, that both examples sound *incredibly* formal, and almost no one talks that way in modern english unless they want to sound posh or very passive aggressive.

---

Maybe you're not concerned with that and just curious about word order, but just in case you or someone else comes across this and wonders how an average person might say this, since as it's written it sounds like either a fantasy novel where some haughty palace guard is trying to keep someone out and be annoying at the same time, or some inexplicably formal desk clerk that's answering a phone.

Assuming it's a situation where you pick up the phone and would like to ask who's calling, you might say

> Hello, who's this?

or

> Can I ask who's calling?

or if you want to sound extra polite

> May I ask who this is?